# How can I get attribute certificate information in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, x509, x509certificate2

I getting certificates from storage:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    
X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Test Certificate Select", "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate", X509SelectionFlag.MultiSelection);
            
    
foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in scollection){
     Console.WriteLine("Simple Name: {0}{1}", x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, true), Environment.NewLine);
}
```

The selected certificate has an attribute certificate. How to get attribute certificate data?

Comment: What is an `attribute certificate`?

Comment: .NET doesn't have any built-in support for X.509 attribute certificates, only X.509 public key certificates.  (I don't think Windows supports attribute certificates, either, so you wouldn't find one in an X509Store)

Comment: Attribute certificate - addition to public key certificate for storing additional information.I thought so. Only in the crypto provider (special equipment) can the attribute certificate be seen. Thanks